# Theorem 4.14 of Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

I have been reading the proof of
[Theorem 4.14](https://books.google.com/books?id=ATNy_Zg3PSsC&pg=PA28) of Karatzas' book. I wonder whether there is a typo in the description of the process $\eta^{(n)}_{t}$ as $\xi^{(n)}_{t+}-\min(\lambda,A_{t})$ whenever $t\in [0,a)$ because in the definition of $T_{n}(\varepsilon)$ it seems that $\eta^{(n)}_{t}$ were defined as $\xi^{(n)}_{t}-\min(\lambda,A_{t})$ (without considering the right hand limit). Now if the correct definition of $\eta^{(n)}_{t}$ is $\xi^{(n)}_{t}-\min(\lambda,A_{t})$ whenever $t\in [0,a)$, why this process turns out to be right-continuous on the whole interval $[0,a]$?

The right-continuity would be necessary in order that $T_{n}(\varepsilon)$ to be a optional time.

Comment: I went to the original literature where this book comes from. I think Ikeda and Watanabe's stochastic differential equations and diffusion processes theorem 6.13 proof is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to prove that\begin{gather*}
\inf\{t \in [0, a] \mid ξ_{t^+} - B_t > ε\} = \inf\{t \in [0, a] \mid ξ_t - B_t > ε\},\tag{1}
\end{gather*}
where (almost surely):

- $ξ_t$ is right-continuous except on a finite set $D$,
- $B_t$ is right-continuous and increasing,
- $ξ_t \geqslant B_t$, and $ξ_t = B_t$ on $D$.

Define $E = \{t \in [0, a] \mid ξ_t - B_t > ε\}$, $F = \{t \in [0, a] \mid ξ_{t^+} - B_t > ε\}$. Note that $E \cap D = \varnothing$, thus\begin{gather*}
E = \{t \in [0, a] \setminus D \mid ξ_t - B_t > ε\}\\
= \{t \in [0, a] \setminus D \mid ξ_{t^+} - B_t > ε\} \subseteq F,
\end{gather*}
which implies that $\inf E \geqslant \inf F$. If $F = \varnothing$, then $\inf E = \inf F = a$. Otherwise denote $t_0 = \inf F$. Since $|D| < ∞$, there exists $δ_0 > 0$ so that $ξ_t$ is right-continuous on $(t_0, t_0 + δ_0)$.

**Case 1:** $t_0 \notin F$. For any $t \in (t_0, t_0 + δ_0)$, if $t \in F$, then$$
ξ_t - B_t = ξ_{t^+} - B_t > ε \Longrightarrow t \in E.
$$
Therefore $t_0 \geqslant \inf E$, so (1) is true.

**Case 2:** $t_0 \in F$. Define $ε_1 = ξ_{t_0^+} - B_{t_0} > ε$. Since$$
\lim_{t → t_0^+} (ξ_t - B_t) = \lim_{t → t_0^+} ξ_t - \lim_{t → t_0^+} B_t = ξ_{t_0^+} - B_{t_0} = ε_1,
$$
then there exists $0 < δ_1 < δ_0$ such that$$
|(ξ_t - B_t) - ε_1| < \frac{1}{2} (ε_1 - ε),\quad\forall t \in (t_0, t_0 + δ_1).
$$
Therefore $(t_0, t_0 + δ_1) \subseteq E$, and $t_0 \geqslant \inf E$, so (1) is true.

Comment: What is $\xi_{t+}$? I don't think the book explains why the right limit exists?

Comment: @Simplyorange The line just below the definition of $ξ_t^{(n)}$ in the book explains this: $ξ_t^{(n)}$ has a right-continuous modification [on each interval $(t_j^{(n)},t_{j+1}^{(n)}]$] by Theorem 3.13.